# Check if string contain one of the value of an array

Tags: php, arrays, search, substring

I have an array of

```
$device_name = ["Xperia Z Ultra", "Xbox One", "Withing", "Win 7", "Surface Pro 4", "Surface Book", "Surface 3", "Play Station 4", "One Plus 2", "Nokia Lumia", "No Img", "Nexus 6p", "Nest", "Moto X", "Mac Pro", "Mac Book", "Mac Book Air", "Lg G4", "Laptop", "Iphone 6", "Iphone 6 S", "Iphone 6 S Plus", "Iphone 6 Plus", "Iphone 5s", "Iphone 5", "Iphone 4", "Ipad", "Ipad Pro", "Hue", "Htc One M9", "Hp Laptop", "Galaxy S6", "Galaxy S6 Edge", "Galaxy S5", "Galaxy Note 5", "Galaxy Note 4", "Galaxy Note 3", "Galaxy Note 2", "Chromecast", "Chrome Book", "Blackberry Z30", "Blackberry Z10", "Blackberry Prev", "Blackberry Bold", "August", "Apple Watch", "Apple Tv", "Ap", "Androidtablet"]
```

I have a string

```
$input = "John's Xperia Z Ultra"
```

I've tried

```
    //Check if containing '
    if (strpos($input, "'") !== false) {
        $pieces = explode(" ", $input); // explode into pieces
        $input = $pieces[1].' '.$pieces[2]; //link them back in

        if (in_array($input, $device_name)) {
            dd('True'); 
        }

    }
```

I'm not sure if what I have right now is the best way to achieve my desired result.

I'm open to any suggestions or a better way.

Comment: Keep in mind that my **$input** contain other string - like `username's` (John's)

Comment: I am a little confused on your coding attempt, do you only want to search for the input value IF it is preceded by a possessive noun?

Answer (score 5):

```
$devices = ["Xperia Z Ultra", "Xbox One", "Withing", "Win 7", "Surface Pro 4", "Surface Book", "Surface 3", "Play Station 4", "One Plus 2", "Nokia Lumia", "No Img", "Nexus 6p", "Nest", "Moto X", "Mac Pro", "Mac Book", "Mac Book Air", "Lg G4", "Laptop", "Iphone 6", "Iphone 6 S", "Iphone 6 S Plus", "Iphone 6 Plus", "Iphone 5s", "Iphone 5", "Iphone 4", "Ipad", "Ipad Pro", "Hue", "Htc One M9", "Hp Laptop", "Galaxy S6", "Galaxy S6 Edge", "Galaxy S5", "Galaxy Note 5", "Galaxy Note 4", "Galaxy Note 3", "Galaxy Note 2", "Chromecast", "Chrome Book", "Blackberry Z30", "Blackberry Z10", "Blackberry Prev", "Blackberry Bold", "August", "Apple Watch", "Apple Tv", "Ap", "Androidtablet"];

$input = "John's Xperia Z Ultra";

$stringContainsDevice = count(array_filter($devices, function($device) use ($input) {
    return stripos($input, $device) !== false;
})) !== 0;
```

So basically you filter the array for items which are contained in the string (I did case insensitive, but if you want case sensitive just change `stripos` to `strpos`) and then see if the filtered array has any items.

Comment: I kept getting `stripos(): needle is not a string or an integer `. Please help !

Comment: Then what else is in your array?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution will be

```
 $contain = 0 ;
 foreach($device_name as $value){
     if(strpos($input, $value)) $contain = 1;
 }
```

contain is 1 if the input contains one of the value of the array otherwise 0

Comment: Nice. I like it. Thanks for simplicity !

Answer (score 1):

The other answers make a function call for every iteration of the `$device_name array`.  Neither one offers an early exit option (`break`).

Instead, I'll refine your `in_array()` process and show you a one-liner that avoids condionals and will only ever make 3 function calls.

```
$device_name = ["Xperia Z Ultra", "Xbox One", "Withing", "Win 7", "Surface Pro 4", "Surface Book", "Surface 3", "Play Station 4", "One Plus 2", "Nokia Lumia", "No Img", "Nexus 6p", "Nest", "Moto X", "Mac Pro", "Mac Book", "Mac Book Air", "Lg G4", "Laptop", "Iphone 6", "Iphone 6 S", "Iphone 6 S Plus", "Iphone 6 Plus", "Iphone 5s", "Iphone 5", "Iphone 4", "Ipad", "Ipad Pro", "Hue", "Htc One M9", "Hp Laptop", "Galaxy S6", "Galaxy S6 Edge", "Galaxy S5", "Galaxy Note 5", "Galaxy Note 4", "Galaxy Note 3", "Galaxy Note 2", "Chromecast", "Chrome Book", "Blackberry Z30", "Blackberry Z10", "Blackberry Prev", "Blackberry Bold", "August", "Apple Watch", "Apple Tv", "Ap", "Androidtablet"];

$input = "John's Xperia Z Ultra";

var_export(in_array(array_slice(explode("'s ",$input,2),-1)[0],$device_name));  // true
```

Here is how it works:

- First, explode the string on `'s` (single-quote,s,space) AND limit the number of elements to 2.  This means if `'s` is found, there will be 2 elements, if not, there will be 1 element.
- Second, remove the last element generated by `explode()`.  This *can* be done with `end()`, but not in the same line -- you'd need to declare a new variable just to handle this data.  The `array_slice()`'s second parameter (`-1`) means extract the last element.
- Third pull the sliced element (convert to a string) by accessing the zero-indexed element.  This *can* be done with `current()` but again, you'd need to declare a new variable.
- Finally, do your `in_array()` call.

Here is a [demo that runs three different input cases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83809234a4641f5c78c45b93bd9739cc9157fdee).

p.s. Your original method is good, it just needs a limit on `explode()`.